# In DAX, how do I create a table variable that removes one of the user selected filters?

Tags: powerbi, dax, ssas-tabular

I have a multi-step process to calculate a measure with mixed grains. The entire thing works except that I am failing to remove the user selection in the very first step of the process.

I need an intial table variable that removes the user selected date, and this is what I wrote:

```
VAR MyFactsAllDates = CALCULATETABLE('Base Fact Table of Facts'  
                                     , ALL('Base Fact Table of Facts'[PeriodDate])   )
```

That tests out to prove it is not removing the filter.

Of course I can remove the filter using ALL(), like this:

```
VAR MyTableOfAllDates = CALCULATETABLE(ALL('Base Fact Table of Facts'  )
```

However, that removes any potential slicing context.

I am having trouble seeing another way to write that removal of the filter on PeriodDate column. How can I write it differently?

Comment: What field is used for the user's date slicer ?

Comment: The user is selecting 'Calendar'[Period] and the 'Calendar' table is related to the fact table via 'Calendar'[Calendar Date] column.

Comment: Have you tried CALCULATETABLE('Base Fact Table of Facts'  ,                  ALL('Calendar'[Period]   ))?

Comment: That did it. I had tried CALCULATETABLE('Base Fact Table of Facts' , ALL('Calendar'[Calendar Date] )) but not on [Period] -- I thought the related column would be the one. That's great. Thank you. Please -- if you wish -- write it as an answer and I'll give it a green check.  :-)

Comment: Ah, it's ok. I am not here for the green, just happy to help :)

Comment: Something you might find interesting: https://www.sqlbi.com/articles/managing-all-functions-in-dax-all-allselected-allnoblankrow-allexcept/

Comment: Thank you. I read that link. It's a very good explanation. Funny, in the article, it was said that a better name for the function would be REMOVEFILTER and actually in the newest version of SSAS Tabular (for SQL 2019) there is a REMOVEFILTERS function.